# Where can we see and learn about the Winter Bash 2022 hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I earned hats on CV!

I earned **secret** hats on CV!

Where are these secrets divulged? This is very important stuff, people!

Comment: There's an annual Meta thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f-%ef%b8%8f

Comment: Make that an answer, pretty please! :)

Comment: For some reason the site isn't letting me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am totally stealing the comment by @Sycorax to answer.

[There is an annual Meta.SE thread for revealing hats and their meanings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f-%ef%b8%8f).

Now you know. Knowledge is power. Power corrupts, and oops I just made you all a little more corrupt.

Comment: I already am missing those pretty hats!

Answer (score 4):

You can find the Winter Bash 2022 Leaderboard at https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard. By the way, as far as the number of hats earned is concerned, Cross Validated got the 13th position!

Comment: Who said 13 is unlucky!

Comment: Not at all, it's prime!